# Removing .php extension from URL not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have added .htaccess file to my directory. When I am writing http://lootainment.in/koovs its working. But when I am writing http://lootainment.in/koovs/ its not working. My htaccess file code is following :-

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 2):

Make trailing slash optional in your rule and remove directory check condition:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php
```

Comment: Isn't `^(.*)$` greedy enough to match literally anything?

Comment: Yes that's true, that's why I used `.+?` to make it a lazy match.

Comment: Ah.. so it doesn't make crazy things like `index/?var=123.php`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
RewriteRule ^([^\.|/]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: "Try this" - please add an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
At first check your php.ini settings for Server API if your server api is 1)apache, 2)apache2filter, 3)apache2handler or like then only you can use .htaccess file. In htaccess file if your php version is php5 then use <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> block to write this code
try this code
RewriteEngine On
# Remove .php-extension from url
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
 RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php
```